# jQuery, Select by attribute value, adding new attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an anchor in my HTML. it has a page attribute with a value. So everytime it is clicked I use the page attribute value in my js. Now I want to set a style attribute with a background color to show that a certain a element is selected. So I have to select the element by page attribute and add a new attribute with a value to the a element.

How do I handle that?

Comment: Show us the code please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With HTML like:

```
<a href='#' page='1'>Link 1</a>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​<br />
```

you could do:

```
$('a[page=1]').addClass('selected').attr('test', 'hi!');​
```

(i.e. better to change display using a css class [e.g. 'selected'] than the style attribute - but the attr call there shows how to add an attribute).

Comment: but I want to have the selected a element to have selected class, all other elements should not have this class, so how do I remove the class when an other element is selected?

Answer (score 3):

To select an element by attribute value, you can use this syntax:

```
$('[attribName="value here"]')
```

Where `attribName` should be replaced with attribute name such as `name`, `title`, etc.

To add a new attribute value, you can use the [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method.

**Example:**

```
$('[attribName="value here"]').attr('attribute name', 'attribute value');
```

And this is how you can change the background color:

```
$('[attribName="value here"]').css('background-color', 'green');
```

Note you should replace dummy attribute names and values as per your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're asking.. do you need to find the a elemenent with a certain value for "page" and change its background?

```
$("a[page='value']").css('background-color', 'color-code');
```

Comment: thanks that works, but the color I specify in color-code stays when I click on an other a element. It should switch back to default. any idea how to do that?

Comment: You use null to unset a css attribute. $("a[page='value']").css('background-color', null).