# jQuery : select all element with custom attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery, Select by attribute value, adding new attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724245/jquery-select-by-attribute-value-adding-new-attribute)
>   [jQuery - How to select by attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9210073/jquery-how-to-select-by-attribute)

please consider this code:

```
<p>11111111111111</p>
<p MyTag="nima">2222222222</p>
<p>33333333333</p>
<p MyTag="Sara">>4444444444</p>
```

how I can select All `p` tag with attribute `MyTag`?

thanks

Comment: could this page help you? http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 202, accepted):

Use the ["has attribute" selector](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/):

```
$('p[MyTag]')
```

Or to select one where that attribute has a specific value:

```
$('p[MyTag="Sara"]')
```

There are [other selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) for "attribute value starts with", "attribute value contains", etc.

Comment: If there are multiple p tags with custom attribute and I want to select which is inside specific div?

Comment: @Jnana - Select the div first, then use `.find()` to get the p element inside it. Or combine the selectors, e.g., if the div has an id: `$('#idOfDiv p[MyTag]')`.

Comment: I have done something like this. $('#parent_div').find('[data-action^="click-target"]'). Thanks

Comment: another solution would be to use this $("[id=choose]")

Comment: @code-it - I don't understand what you mean, that's the same syntax I put in my answer, except you're specifying an attribute not applicable to the OP's HTML. (And one wouldn't do that for an `id` attribute given the is a specific selector for that purpose.)

Answer (score 11):

As described by the link I've [given in comment](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), this

```
$('p[MyTag]').each(function(index) {
  document.write(index + ': ' + $(this).text() + "<br>");});
```

works ([playable example](http://jsbin.com/epiros/2/edit)).