# strip_html - how to select/allowed specific <p> tag

Tags: php, jquery

```
<p data-p-id="787f8218ddeb003c4e4115791dbd3d64">I WANT TO SELECT THIS TEXT</p>
<p data-p-id="fffa2fbdd488d59cd9006f69c502da0c">AND THIS TEXT</p>`
<p data-p-id="8283e3fcff081b550ad589abf1c97d96">AND THIS TEXT</p>
<p data-p-id="9a20d2be577597b30b603e168918384e">THIS TEXT ALSO</p>
```

I just want to select `<p>` tag with **data-p-id** on it.
How can I do it in jQuery or strip_html in PHP?

Please help...sorry for poor english!

Comment: what you want to strip it or target it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191386/jquery-how-to-find-an-element-based-on-a-data-attribute-value

Comment: This has been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392463/jquery-select-all-element-with-custom-attribute

Comment: @Mr.coder to be more specific i want to strip it sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP's `strip_tag` — Strip HTML and PHP tags from a string.

If you want to select all `p` tag and then get the `data-p-id` on each `p` tag, this is what you do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// When page loads
$(function()
{
    $('p').each(function() {
        console.log('data-p-id = ' + $(this).attr('data-p-id'));
    });
});  

</script>


<p data-p-id="787f8218ddeb003c4e4115791dbd3d64">I WANT TO SELECT THIS TEXT</p>
<p data-p-id="fffa2fbdd488d59cd9006f69c502da0c">AND THIS TEXT</p>
<p data-p-id="8283e3fcff081b550ad589abf1c97d96">AND THIS TEXT</p>
<p data-p-id="9a20d2be577597b30b603e168918384e">THIS TEXT ALSO</p>
```

Check the console output and you will see this:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much sir ....thanks for the quick reply....follow up question.. how about in php sir is there a way to select <p> tag with p-data-id on it???

Comment: @eman_invok05 See: [DOMDocument Class](http://www.php.net//manual/en/class.domdocument.php#class.domdocument)

Comment: You should avoid using `attr` instead use `prop`. [Reference](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#attr-versus-prop-)

Comment: @RahilWazir thank you sir...i will check this one :D thanks for your quick reply

Answer (score 0):

In jquery: $("div[data-p-id]")

For example, to set the background golour of all these div tags to yellow, use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div[data-p-id]").css("background-color","yellow");});
</script>
```

Remember to load the jquery library before calling the above function.