# jQuery add html to p tag custom element name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add text to a p tag using jQuery...

My tag looks like this:

```
<p class="form-control-static" data-display="ccnum">
                                                    </p>
```

I want it to look like this:

```
    <p class="form-control-static" data-display="ccnum">4111111111111111
                                                    </p>
```

Basically, this is the confirmation page of a checkout form and I am trying to display the value someone submitted from the previous page:

I can get that value by doing this:

```
$('#ccnum').val();
```

but I can't figure out how to set it in the p tag.

Thanks.

P.S.  Please don't roast me for displaying the cc...  I am going to only show the last four character back to the user.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `text()` method to set the text of an element:

```
$('.form-control-static').text($('#ccnum').val());
```

Comment: Hi Rory, but that only gets me to the "form-control-static" class...  How do I go one level further to the "data-display" element?

Comment: You can use the attribute selector: `$('.form-control-static[data-display="ccnum"])`, or better yet add a unique id or class to this element to identify it.

Answer (score 1):

as usual I found an answer after I posted and waited...

```
$('p[data-display="ccnum"]').html(ccnum);
```

I found the baseline from this SO thread: [jQuery : select all element with custom attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392463/jquery-select-all-element-with-custom-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

**TRY this**

http://jsfiddle.net/rxb84fxp/2/

html

```
<p id="form-control-static" data-display="ccnum">
</p>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("form-control-static").innerHTML = "whatever";
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this didn't work for me...  Got an "undefined is not a function" error...

Comment: Thank you for your help, but if there is more than one "form-control-static" id defined, this will fail...  I put the correct answer below.