# jQuery: hiding elements with special attributes

Tags: jquery

How do you go about hiding elements based on special attributes like so:

```
<div data-collapsed-icon="music">hide this element</div>
```

So, hiding elements where `data-collapsed-icon` attribute equals `music`?

Comment: Have you done any research? Key words : `attribute selector`.

Comment: You should really make a simple search before creating a new thread. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392463/jquery-select-all-element-with-custom-attribute)

Comment: well, i think its still useful, this question will show up in google for those who search for "jquery hiding elements with special attributes". i would never thought about searching for "custom attributes", and im sure im not alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors), `[data-collapsed-icon="music"]`:

```
$('[data-collapsed-icon="music"]').hide();
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/030qgwmk/)

But since `[data-collapsed-icon="music"]` is a CSS selector, you could also use:

```
[data-collapsed-icon="music"] {
    display: none;
}
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/a1woa3ky/)

Answer (score 0):

Also, as an alternative, you can accomplish this without jQuery, using CSS only:

```
div[data-collapsed-icon="music"]{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this

```
$('[data-collapsed-icon]').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var attr = $this.attr('data-collapsed-icon');
  if(attr == 'music'){
   $this.hide();
  }
});
```

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/8yy4pz93/

Comment: voted it down because theres a better way as you can see above

Comment: I don't think a down vote applies to a script you just don't want to use. It's still a valid script that totally answers your question. It makes use of Jquery and it hides elements with special attributes that match specific values as you requested. So please explain where does this answer fails so I can understand your down vote?